# Capistrano and sitemap_generator - cannot load such file -- capistrano/sitemap_generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I have been using capistrano for a while and I also use sitemap_generator. But now I wanted to put the sitemap_generator into the deployment process. According to: [Github sitemap generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator#deployments--capistrano) I only need to require it in the capfile.

But once I run capistrano it cannot load the file.

Thx for help

Answer (score 2):

The capistrano tasks included with the sitemap_generator gem are for capistrano 3.0.

Assuming you're probably on 2.x, you can create a task that calls the rake sitemap refresh task for you through bundler.

```
# recipes/sitemap.rb
namespace :sitemap do
  desc "Generate sitemap.xml.gz"
  task :generate, roles: :web do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current && /usr/bin/env bundle exec rake sitemap:refresh RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
  after "deploy:restart", "sitemap:generate"
end
```

This example regenerates the sitemap after the `deploy:restart` task, but the task can be called directly.